# What do I do if parameter of function is the same as a column name

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-function

I have an SQL function which has a parameter name as id. However, I have a column name which has the same name, id. How do I tell the function how to distinguish between the parameter and the column. My function works perfectly if I change the paramter name from id to num, but that is not an option here and I cannot change the column name too.

```
create or replace function
    test(id integer) return text
as $$
    select address
    from customers c
    where c.id = id
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: Change the name of the parameter.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That isn't an option.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am doing homework and the teacher wrote the definition of the function. The function gets auto-tested and if I change the parameter name, the auto-test doesn't work and I get the answer wrong.

Comment: Then change the name of the table column...

Comment: @GMB That isn't an option too. All I can change is the select statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgres allows you to refer to arguments positionally:

```
create or replace function
    test(id integer) return text
as $$
    select address
    from customers c
    where c.id = $1
$$ language sql;
```

I view this as a bad practice and a class should not be encouraging this style.  In fact, you should be encouraged to give names to parameters that are less likely to conflict with other identifiers:

```
create or replace function test (
        in_id integer
) return text
as $$
    select address
    from customers c
    where c.id = in_id
$$ language sql;
```

Answer (score 4):

Does it work if you phrase the query like this?

```
select address
from (select c.id as cid, c.address from customers c) t
where cid = id
```

Comment: This is how I got around it - I used a cte to change the column names in the source table